# Mysql While Loop Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a simple forum script, but when I try and whenever I run my code, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 15
```

Here is the code I'm using

```
while($topic = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `post_count` FROM `topics`))){
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $topic['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $topic['post_count']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Increase your execution time in php.ini

Comment: How long does your SQL query to execute if you enter it manually on your database? How many rows does the table 'topics' contain? You could increase the maximum execution time of a script in your php.ini , but it's never a bad thing to look into optimizing your code.

Comment: check how many records are there in table topics.It might be that there are more number of record which cannot be excuted in 30 sec You can increase execution time. go to php.ini and change the value of max_execution_time from 30 to number of seconds you want

Comment: You shouldn't call `mysql_query` in loop. Call it once, then fetch results. Your loop is infinite now.

Comment: Stop using mysql_query, it was deprecated. Use the mysqli or PDO extensions instead.

Comment: @ManishJangir it would still time out if he set it to 5 years - this is an infinite loop. Also, you should never change max execution time in `php.ini`, it'll affect the entire site. Call [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in a script for which you know it's required instead.

Comment: Its ok, I've got it working. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query will always return a resultset. You then call fetch-array on that resultset, and get the first row. Then you re-run the query, and fetch the the first row. again. and again... that is what we call an infinite loop :)

Just call the query once, and call mysql fetch array on the mysql result you get from that.

as a side note: check the PHP manual for the mysl_ functions.. See the big warning? These functions are deprecated!

Comment: So, store the query in a variable?

Comment: @Isaac you should accept this answer rather than `thanks`.

Comment: Silly "You have to wait 5 mins" feature...

Answer (score 4):

When you are trying this structure, the query is executed over and over again.
Please first try to set the query in a variable and use that in you're while loop:

```
$query = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY!");

while($topic = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    print_r($topic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `mysql_query` in loop. Call it once, then fetch results.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`, `post_count` FROM `topics`");

while ($topic = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
  ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $topic['name']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $topic['post_count']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```